# Populating DB2 Table from SQL Script

Tags: sql, db2

I've written simple SQL scripts before, but I'm no expert, so I'm not even sure that what I'm about to ask can be done. From a DB2 SQL script, I'd like to populate a table from the contents of a different table. Eventually, I am going to be bringing in data from other tables, but I just need to get the basics working first. I'm trying to do this from the DB2 CLP, executing a file.

From looking at manuals, I thought this might possibly work:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
    FOR ROW AS
        SELECT OSN.SWOSNAME, OSN.SWPLATFORM FROM SASH1.LISTOSNAMES OSN
    DO
        INSERT INTO SASH1.VALIDOSES
            VALUES (ROW.OSN.SWOSNAME, 'IBM', ROW.OSN.SWOSNAME, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Y', ROW.OSN.SWPLATFORM, NULL);
    END FOR;
END
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following
"SN.SWPLATFORM, NULL)".  Expected tokens may include:  "<delim_semicolon>".
LINE NUMBER=6.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

It's fairly obvious that I don't know what I'm doing here. Is it possible to do something like this (populating a table from data in another table), without having to create SQL Procedures or Functions in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating things, all you need to do is to insert the result of the select, make sure you specify the column names (I used col1, ...)

```
INSERT INTO SASH1.VALIDOSES
    (col1, col2, ... ,coln)
SELECT SWOSNAME, 'IBM', SWOSNAME, 'Y', SWPLATFORM 
FROM SASH1.LISTOSNAMES
```

Note that you probably don't have to specify NULL (it is default, unless there is a default value specified for the column that you would like to override with NULL)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Lennart! I knew I was missing something, this is very easy.

Comment: Just mark my answer as a solution and we are even ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Despite what @Lennart said about overcomplicating things, if you insist on using an anonymous block realize that the entire block is a *single SQL statement* and as such must have a terminator character at the end. Since you also must have the default statement terminators, the semicolons, *within* the block, the block itself must use some other character as the terminator. "@" is commonly used, so you would put the "@" character after the `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` statement and execute the file:

```
db2 -td@ -f <yourfile>
```

Comment: Aha! This explains much. Thanks, Mustaccio! Even though I will use Lennart's suggestion, your reply will be useful if I do need to use blocks in the future.